# What is CSS's Default Border Color

Tags: css, border

Does anyone know what color CSS default the border color to? It's a dark grey but I want to use as a background color somewhere else but I can't figure out specifically what the color is.

Comment: it's the color of the element ... so check the default color of the element

Comment: Default value for `border-color` is whatever the `currentcolor` is set to, which depends on the element'w own `color` declaration.
Default value for color is browser-dependant, normally black. But different elements can have different `color` and / or `border-color`, depending on the browser's user-agent stylesheet. For instance, on Chrome, text are simply black (actually `RGB(0, 0, 0)`), while `input` elements have the same black color and `RGB(238, 238, 238)` border-color. So it all comes down to what element and browser are you asking about...

Comment: It sounds like you already know the color but don't know how to change it. What exactly is your question or problem?